# Kshell. Use a file mask in a variable

Tags: shell, scripting

I try to use a variable in my kshell script but can't get a good result. Please help.

```
FileMask='*.ext'
echo "FILEMASK: $FileMask"
/bin/executable -inputMask $FileMask
```

`echo` displays the `FILEMASK: *.ext`

But in the line with executable, instead of `*.ext` as a argument of the attribute `-inputMask`, I get the whole listing of all the `.ext` files from current the directory.

How do I use a content of a variable, but not evaluate that?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the use of the variable i.e.:

```
/bin/executable -inputMask "$FileMask"
```